# Topaz Signature Applet not connecting to Serial ClipGem on COM1

Tags: java, applet, serial-port, topaz-signatures

Here is my problem:

I cannot connect to serial port COM1 using [ClipGem](http://www.topazsystems.com/products/clipgem.asp) (Model: T-C912-B1) in a Java Applet.

I have verified that the Java class I built works as desktop application extending `Frame` and I can successfully capture signatures on COM1 and also on a ClipGem USB (Model: T-C912-HSB-R)

```
public class SigPlusSimpleDemo extends Frame
```

Next, I changed `Frame` to `JApplet` and try again using my new applet with the USB ClipGem to verify the applet is still successfully capturing signatures and USB still works as expected and it does.

However, when I try the same applet on serial port signature pad, I cannot connect to it. Remember, I already verified that it's working as a desktop application.

**Does anyone know some reasons that can be causing this problem on COM1?**

**Has anyone experienced this problem?**

**Am I missing something?**

*Note: I am familiar with Java and have some programming experience, but I am no expert. Also, I have been going back and forth with Topaz Systems looking for a solution and I am currently waiting for another reply from them.*

Comment: Have you checked the basic permissions and ensured you can do simple raw reading from the COM port in Java?

Comment: COM1 works for same java code run from the command line, the problem comes when run as an applet in the browser. Do you believe this is a permissions issue? If so, where do I look (java.policy/security)? I have signed the applet jar. Any quick hacks to determine if permissions?

Comment: by "COM1 works" are you saying that directly access COM1 (not using Topaz libraries) works? I'm honestly not knowledgeable with Java but I looked at this question because I know some about the Topaz signature pads. It appears [you're not alone](http://www.google.com/?q=access+com+port+java+from+applet) though

Comment: Works on com1 through desktop. Doesn't work in applet. I haven't tried COM1 in applet without topaz library. I will try that next

Comment: If you can, make a very minimal test case and post it here. That will help you get more people to help you (though sadly probably won't be in time for your bounty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code works fine as a desktop application, a way to work around this issue would be to deploy your application as a Java Web Start application instead of an applet.

Comment: This probably is the best answer. However, I am going to abandon getting COM1 to work with this applet. Maybe, I will come back to it. Our solution is going to be switch to all USB tablets. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a look at the Java console when running as an applet? You'll probably see the stacktrace of an exception.

Comment: Yes. The only thing in the console is my custom log messages. "Trying USB, Trying COM1" etc. Any ideas on what would prevent COM1 and Java Applet?

Comment: Is the applet properly signed?

Comment: I self signed it with jarsigner using a key I created. Does that count as properly signed?

Comment: Yes, an unsigned applet would not be allowed to reach the COM port.